# React Native: Change placeholder text display from right to left

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, autocomplete

I use a library ״**react-native-autocomplete-input**״

Is there a way to change the placeholder text display from right to left ?

[image]

this is my example code :

```
<Autocomplete
                data={
                  autoCompleteWaterSourceData?.length === 1 &&
                  autoCompleteWaterSourceData[0]
                    ? []
                    : autoCompleteWaterSourceData
                }
                placeholder={placeholder1}
                value={querySourceCode}
                autoCorrect={false}
                onChangeText={setQuerySourceCode}
                flatListProps={{
                  keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'always',
                  keyExtractor: (_, idx) => idx.Water_Source_Code,
                  renderItem: ({
                    item: { Water_Source_Code, Water_Source_Name },
                  }) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() =>
                        setQuerySourceCode(
                          Water_Source_Code + ' ' + Water_Source_Name
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.autoCompleteText}>
                        {Water_Source_Code + ' ' + Water_Source_Name}
                      </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  ),
                }}
              />
```

Comment: add example of expected out put string.

Comment: in my example in the picture you can see "TUBAZA" and its view from left side to right side so i want to view it from right side to left side .

Comment: so you just want to `AZABUT` on finish input or every time character enter into input

Comment: i edit the image so you can understand what i mean .
just change side of the text after u choose from list.

Comment: you just need to add css some where like `.textRight > input { text-align:right !important}.` and use className="textRight" or create minimul reproduction for us so we can play with it.

Comment: please show me your meaning in my example code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an expo example.
what i do is

1. use `renderTextInput` prop for `Autocomplete` element and provide our own input field.
2. add style for it.

check this on [expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@mohitsharma07/rn-autocomplete-input-example)